# Unused container warning when iterating over values of a specific key in QMultiMap

Tags: qt, containers, qmultimap

i get an "allocating unneeded temporary container" warning when i try to iterate over the values of a specific key in a QMultiMap:

```
QMultiHash<QString,QString> testMap;
        
        for (auto &&value : testMap.values("Specific Key"))
        {
            
        }
```

Is there a better way of doin this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the snippet below to remove this warning:

```
QMultiHash<QString,QString> testMap;

const auto values = testMap.values("Specific Key");      
for (auto &&value : values)
{
            
}
```

Comment: yeah, i read that too. that seems like a crude workaround though. is there no "inline" version to fix that?

Comment: in a for loop, the end condition is evaluated at each step. It means a temporary container is assigned at each step when `testMap.values("Specific Key")` is called.

Using a const container avoid this temporary assignation.